# Aligning a picture and words in a presentation

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I wanted to work on a presentation sheet which looks like this:
[image]
but I don't succeed in aligning the picture with the right ragged text "1ere année". It is *under* it and not aligned and I wonder how I could align the text with the *center* of the image. This is the code:

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{newpage}\noindent
  \begin{flushleft}\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{test2.png}\hfill$1^{\text{ère}$ année\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}\huge\textbf{TD 4 - Résistance Des Matériaux}\end{center}
\begin{center}\textbf{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}\end{center}
\Large\begin{center}\textbf{\textit{Simulation d'un naufrage}}\end{center}
\end{newpage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}\hfill 1\textsuperscript{ère} année
\begin{center}
{\huge\textbf{TD 4 - Résistance Des Matériaux}}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hrule
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\Large\textbf{\textit{Simulation d'un naufrage}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to achieve the desired vertically centered alignment of ht eimage and the text, I have used the option `valign=c` that is introduced by the `adjustbox` package.

Other changes apart from the original question: I have removed superfluous environments (`flushleft`, `center`). Instead of exploiting math mode to insert superscript text, I have used the appropriate `\textsuperscript` command. Instead of using repeated `-` to achieve a horizontal rule, I have used the `\hrule` command, that inserts a horizontal rule that automatically spans the textwidth. For the adjustment of the vertical distances bewteen the rule and the lines of text, I used `\vspace` commands.

Answer (score 1):

You should put both the image and the text in a `minipage`. The following example does this, but I also implemented several other changes that I would propose for your specific design.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\centering

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.18\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test2.png}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}\raggedleft
    1\textsuperscript{\text{ère}} année
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\textbf{\huge TD 4 -- Résistance Des Matériaux}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\hrule

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\textbf{\textit{\Large Simulation d'un naufrage}}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]